# In a char array, how do I change all the elements to the same?

Tags: arrays, c

I have a 2D char array (3x3) and I want to change every element to a space ' '.

```
char array[3][3];
```

How can I use the array's element "coordinates" for this ?

Can't add headers

Comment: Use `memset()` to set all bytes to the same value.

Comment: If you *do* want to use the array's "coordinates", you'll need two nested `for` loops, e.g. `for (int row=0; row<3; row++) { for (int col=0; col<3; col++) { array[row][col] = ' '; }}`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the coordinates. [`memset()`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memset.3.html) can be used to set all `char` elements to the same value.

```
memset(array, ' ', sizeof(array));
```

(note that this cannot be used for multi-byte types such as `int` except for special case like setting to zero)

Comment: I forgot to mention I can't add headers tho, with memset it asks me to add #include <string.h>

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear in your question if you want to use the values of `array` as a string, in such case:

```
size_t rows = sizeof array / sizeof *array;
size_t cols = sizeof *array / sizeof **array;

for (size_t row = 0; row < rows; row++)
{
    size_t col = 0;

    for (; col < cols - 1; col++)
    {
        array[row][col] = ' ';
    }
    array[row][col] = '\0';
}
```

if you want to fill the whole array with spaces:

```
size_t rows = sizeof array / sizeof *array;
size_t cols = sizeof *array / sizeof **array;

for (size_t row = 0; row < rows; row++)
{
    for (size_t col = 0; col < cols; col++)
    {
        array[row][col] = ' ';
    }
}
```

Since the second snippet doesn't null-terminate the elements of the array, they can not be used as strings.

Comment: Thank you,
for (size_t row = 0; row < rows; row++)
{
    for (size_t col = 0; col < cols; col++)
    {
        array[row][col] = ' ';
    }
}
Solved the problem